# скрипт для отлова ботов

Tags: javascript, html

подскажите скрипт для отлова ботов на сайте

Comment: вы имеете ввиду ботов которые фейковые заказы делают на ленде?

Answer (score 1):

Если интересует отлов поисковых роботов Яндекса, Google или других поисковых систем, то можно проверять User Agent. Для подробной информации об используемых User Agent можно найти на офф. страницах поисковых систем.

Comment: ситуация такая что лью траф на ленд и хотелось бы чтоб боты не смогли заходить на мой ленд.

Comment: @Samvel добавьте полную информацию в свой вопрос, иначе он скорее всего будет закрыт.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы боты поисковиков не индексировали ваш сайт вам следует в корневую директорию сайта положить файл robots.txt со следующим содержанием:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Первый параметр указывает, что правило распространяется на всех поисковых ботов.

Второй параметр указывает, что индексирование запрещено для всего сайта.

Так же можно управлять конкретными поисковыми системами:

```
User-agent: Yandex
User-agent: Googlebot
...
```